# Download Cookies from MobileFirst Platform's Mobile Site

Tags: cookies, ibm-mobilefirst

I'd like to understand if there's any cookie downloaded in the Desktop/Mobile browser, while browsing the MobileFirst Platform's Mobile Site.
Is there any information written inside it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, yes, there will be a cookie called WL_PERSISTENT_COOKIE used for working with authentication realms - you can find out more [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding_predefined_worklight_authentication_realms_and_security_tests11?lang=en).

In general, it's not too hard in most browsers to see if a cookie is set by any particular site, including the MFP mobile web environment - for example, [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en) are some instructions on how to do that in Chrome.